# How to connect to Aptana studio 3 using ssh + password? (SFTP)

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, sftp, aptana

I rented a VPS a few days ago and been messing around with it for a little while. One thing I'm really struggling with: getting an easy file exchange system for an eventual website I want to build. Ideally I'd want just a folder on my MacBook that I can link directly with an identical folder on the Linux server (preferably /var/www/) with Aptana Studio 3 (I really like their IDE).

So far my main problem is that I can't connect (through Aptana or other file systems like FileZilla) with SFTP on the server, because either I can input the private key to Aptana and it won't have the user's password, or I can input the password but it won't have the ssh key :(

I've tried several things, such as setting ssh's config `strictmodes no`, changing `usePAM no` and `PasswordAuthentication no`. All this does is not allowing me to login to the server anymore AT ALL, forcing me to hard reset everything on the server.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Actions after fresh installation of the OS by DigitalOcean:

1. `adduser user01`
2. `visudo` insert `user01 ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`
3. `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` change: `PermitRootLogin no` and add: `UseDNS no` (no idea why, but a tutorial of DigitalOcean told me to xD), `AllowUser user01`

These are all the steps I've taken after logging in to the server for the first time. On my home computer I created an ssh key and DigitalOcean (I think) used this as a verified key during the installation of the OS.

My main question: When connecting with ssh myself through the commandline, I use my private key to connect (I think), but I also have to type in a password to login as my `user01`. When adding a server in FileZilla or Aptana, I have the option to either choose SFTP with a password, or SFTP with key authentication, not both. Clearly I must be doing something wrong, so my question is what.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't really handle open-ended questions asking for "tips". Could you edit your question to include specific details of how you've configured things, and what kind of errors or other failures you're getting? What happens when you try to connect using the ssh/sftp command-line utilities, instead of through aptana?

Comment: Thanks @Kenster, I changed the question a bit, but it's still a pretty open question because I don't really know what is going wrong. Hope the additional information helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed what happened: the first time I setup the server, DigitalOcean put my public SSH in the server's /.ssh/authorized_keys, but after my first reset this was lost, that's why I always had to login with a password. Manually nano'ing in the public key fixed everything :)